# How to make a sum by using group by?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I have the following dataset and I want to sum the values of the column UnitPrice grouping by CustomerID.

[image]

I'm trying the following way but despite the new column is being added the values are not being filled

```
data['TotalEN'] = round(data.groupby(['SalesOrderID'])['UnitPrice'].sum(),2)
```

I tried to print the function if is calculating the values correctly and indeed it is

```
print(data.groupby(['CustomerID'])['UnitPrice'].sum())
```

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the shape of the output from the groupby operation will be different than the shape of your dataframe. You will need to use the `transform` method on the groupby object to restore the correct shape you need:

```py
data['TotalEN'] = data.groupby(['SalesOrderID'])['UnitPrice'].transform('sum').round(2)
```

You can read more about `transform` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).